# Can I grep each file of directory and save output to one file? Example code included

Tags: grep

I am running a grep command on each file in a directory. I want the outputs to be appended into the same file. Is this possible?

Here is what I am using unsuccessfully:

```
for f in /directory/*.txt
do
grep -Eo "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" $f >> one_output_file.txt
done
```

I am grepping out a number from each file and I want the numbers to be listed together in ONE output file. Possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not drop the for loop and do

```
grep -Eoh "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" /directory/*.txt > one_output_file.txt
```